# intellisense for JSDT libraries not working with Eclipse 3.7

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete, jsdt

I have eclipse 3.6 with JSDT 1.2. I have integrated java-script editor in to my MultiPageEditorPart. I have added javascript facet to my project programatically and added a custom library called 'Studio library' for providing intelli-sense. The integrated javascript editor works fine with the intellisense. **BUT**

The same code fails in 3.7.1. i.e the **intelli-sense fails**.I am using eclipse 3.7.1 with JSDT 1.3.1. One more thing to note is the other than base browser library options (**'Window'**) no other intelli-sense options appear in the JS editor. (**This is not related to my custom library**)

I debugged the 3.6 and 3.7.1 codes and compared it against each other. In **CompletionEngine** class in **complete(ICompilationUnit sourceUnit, int completionPosition, int pos)** method the **e.qualifiedBinding** object is propulated with intelli-sense options in 3.6 where as in 3.7.1 the object is null.

I am not able to find a reason for this. Any clue or help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This is when both editors are editing the same file in the same project?

Comment: Not necessarily. the behaviour is independent of files or project. The intelli-sense deosnt just work for added js libraries in 3.7.

Comment: Hi nitind any solution to the problem are you able to understand the problem?

Comment: I wanted to know whether you could reproduce it with the same file in both editors.

Comment: The problem is reproducible with the same file in both the editors.

Comment: Did installing the facet set up the JavaScript Include Path properly?  Is the file under a Source Folder on that Include Path?

Comment: Please look at the below path entries. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.WebProject">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="hide" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.launching.baseBrowserLibrary"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="**BPM Studio Script Library**"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path=""/>
</classpath>

Comment: I am not able to add screen shots. I can put u a detailed report if u can point to a forum which allows screenshots

Comment: The Eclipse Forums let you do screen shots.  http://eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.webtools .

Comment: sorry for the delay. I have posted some screen shots here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/850780/#msg_850780